# rpsec actionmailer preview doesn't exist? What's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using Rspec in my rails app and I ran this code

```
rails generate mailer UserMailer account_activation password_reset
```

But it didn't generate any preview files in my spec folder. It does if I were using minitest and had a test folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

RSpec doesn't give you mailer preview files (I'm not sure minitest does either, but I'll take your word for it). However, there are some handy gems that let you look at mailers once they are sent like: https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener